# Change the subscription state of an observable with another observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

If you run the code below you'll see in the console that an xhr request is sent regardless of whether or not I'm `subscribed` to `subject`. I'd like to not make those request when I'm not subbed to it.

```
// npm install rxjs
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');

let subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(null)
Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).subscribe(i => someApiCall(i));
//at this point xhr request will be sent every second

function someApiCall(i){
    // retrieve some data
    console.log("xhr request sent")
    subject.next(i);
}

//so here we are gonna subscribe to the subject, xhr made prior 
//to this subscription are useless
let subscription;
setTimeout(() => subscription = subject.subscribe(i => console.log(i)),2500);
setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(),6000);
// now we are unsubscribing but the xhr req keep going
```

The reason I'm using the behaviorSubject and not subscribing directly on the observable is because I  want the last value from the last xhr request instantly when I resubscribe.

Comment: I'm a little confused, `Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).subscribe(i => someApiCall(i));` is never unsubscribed from, and is immediately invoked.  So, to me the "xhr request sent" message will be logged every second while the page is loaded.  Then after 2 xhr message, you should start seeing the numbers being logged, and you should only see 4 numbers logged.  Is that not what is happening? Is that what the question is about?

Comment: @joe_coolish yes that's what happens, I'd like the request made only when I can see the numbers, does that make sens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://acutmore.jsbin.com/bepiho/2/edit?js,console

```js
const { Observable } = Rx;

function someApiCall(i){
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    console.log("xhr request sent")
    observer.next(i);
    observer.complete();
  });
}

const data = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
  // map each value to the values of someApiCall
  . mergeMap(i => someApiCall(i))
  // share the values through a replaySubject
  .publishReplay(1)
  // Only connect to the source when there is at least one subscriber
  .refCount();

data
  .take(5)
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));

data
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

Worth noting this won't work as expected if everyone does `.take(1)` when they subscribe because everyone will get the value in the `ReplaySubject` and then instantly unsubscribe before a new xhrRequest will be made.

i.e. Something needs to keep it *alive* long enough for the interval to keep firing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.ShareReplay(1)` instead of using a `BehaviourSubject`. That way you can keep it lazy and cache the last value of your xhr call.

```
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .mergeMap(I => doXhr())
  .shareReplay(1);

source.subscribe(console.log)
```